# pymongo why we can use a dot to get a collection instance?

Tags: python, pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
DBC = MongoClient("localhost").test.test
```

Just as the snippet above, we can use just a `.` instead of `get_database("test")` and `get_collection("test")` to get a database instance or a collection instance. Despite the convenience, I wonder what makes this *syntactic sugar* happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [*`__getattr__()` magic method*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) making dot notation/attribute lookup happen.

Let's look into the source code. `MongoClient` class [defines `__getaattr__`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L911) method and instantiates a `Database` class by name:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    """Get a database by name.
    Raises :class:`~pymongo.errors.InvalidName` if an invalid
    database name is used.
    :Parameters:
      - `name`: the name of the database to get
    """
    if name.startswith('_'):
        raise AttributeError(
            "MongoClient has no attribute %r. To access the %s"
            " database, use client[%r]." % (name, name, name))
    return self.__getitem__(name)

def __getitem__(self, name):
    """Get a database by name.
    Raises :class:`~pymongo.errors.InvalidName` if an invalid
    database name is used.
    :Parameters:
      - `name`: the name of the database to get
    """
    return database.Database(self, name)
```

And the [same goes for the `Database` class](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/database.py#L211).